# How to implement AuthInvalidCredentialsException?

Tags: java, android, firebase

I have implemented `Firebase` phone authentication in android. and in the fragment where I am getting OTP. and also checking that the user is currently existing or not. If the user currently exists I am sending it to test fragment otherwise to registration fragment. below is my code.

But not getting how to implement this piece of code:

```
(task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                                // The verification code entered was invalid
                                buttonOtpVerify.setText("Verify OTP");
                                progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                             Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Verification Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

This is my main code. with this I want to implement above code:

```
private void signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
        FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        bundle.putString("phone", number);

                        DocumentReference documentReference = firebaseFirestore.collection("Merchants").document(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
                        documentReference.get().addOnSuccessListener(documentSnapshot -> {
                            if (documentSnapshot.exists()) {
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Login Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                                Test test = new Test();
                                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainerDashboard, test);
                                fragmentTransaction.commit();
                            }
                            else {
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Verified Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                                RegistrationFragment registrationFragment = new RegistrationFragment();
                                registrationFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainerDashboard, registrationFragment);
                                fragmentTransaction.commit();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
    }
```

Comment: what is the problem?, you send the otp , user enters , he logs in , if he enter incorrect code , `addOnFailureListener` executes , where is the problem?

Comment: @AbhinavChauhan that I am not getting how to add with this code.

Comment: i am having hard time understand the exact problem, will you please explain more?

Comment: @AbhinavChauhan can you tell your mail ID.

Comment: check karna mail kar denge. thodi der baad

Comment: e-mail address note kar liya hoga na?

Comment: Iss par mail kar do deeskshaparna@gmail.com